# Npm install fail with node 15 ( Not LTS ) "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0"

Tags: node.js, npm

npm install fail with below dependency "@angular-devkit/build-angular" :
sample package.json

```
  {
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0"
  }
}
```

I am using node V15.5.1 npm v7.3.0

I'm getting below errors :

> npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.0.5 npm ERR! node_modules/typescript npm
> ERR!   peer typescript@">=3.9 <4.1" from @angular/compiler-cli@10.2.4
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli npm ERR!     peer
> @angular/compiler-cli@">=10.0.0-next.0 < 11" from
> @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1000.8 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular npm ERR!  npm ERR! Could
> not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer typescript@">=3.9 < 3.10" from
> @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1000.8 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular

not sure why node/npm is looking for typescript 4.0.5 instead of the version that can suit both the ranges. (peer typescript@">=3.9 <4.1" and peer typescript@">=3.9 < 3.10" )
is this working as expected .

i can able to run the npm install with **--legacy-peer-deps** flag.

is this a problem or its working as designed . why cant npm choose the version which suits both cases

Answer (score 0):

Use LTS version of node, currently 14.15.4. Changing the version depends on your OS and package manager, but at least on MacOS and Homebrew it goes like this:

```
brew update
brew install node@14
brew link --overwrite node@14
```

Comment: thanks for your answer . i like to know is this the expected behaviour going forward in new releases, or some bug with npm.

Comment: Ah, ok I undestood that the question was "how to make it work". It certainly looks like a bug in npm to me and looks like someone (you?) has reported it: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2510 But in general I think it's a good idea to stick with LTS versions when doing angular development.